# On which OSI layer image stegnography is done/handled

Tags: image-processing, steganography, osi

I want to know on which OSI layer image steganography is done with explanations about why it is on that layer. I have tried searching for this everywhere but it was of no use.

Comment: Is [this](http://chemistry47.com/PDFs/OSI%20Model/Hiding%20Data%20in%20the%20OSI%20Network%20Model.pdf) of any use? More importantly, is this even relevant here, since it has to do more with networking and less with programming?

Comment: @Reti43 thanks i finally got my answer

Comment: Consider posting an answer so that future readers would also benefit. As it currently stands, it's not even clear to me what exactly you were after with your question.

Comment: Ok. posted the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are embedding data into your image then it means you are working in presentation layer of OSI model.I got this answer from the link posted above in comments

Comment: There is no such thing as a presentation layer in the real world. It is pointless talking about OSI layers as though they refer to anything real. They don't. You are almost certainly talking about a real existing protocol in the TCP/IP suite, in which case the answer is 'application layer'.